# Property/Relations using Fourier series/transform, which give complete information about all the jump singularities of a function.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fourier-analysis, real-analysis

Consider a function which has only jump singularities of the form of the function itself or one of its derivatives jumping. Now let $\hat{f}(k)$ be its Fourier transform/series. We know the [decay of the magnitude](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10854/2987) of the Fourier series/transform depend on how many times $f$ is continuously differentiable.

But now what I am asking is are there any such similar relations which not only tells how many times $f$ is continuously differentiable, but also gives complete information about all the jump singularities of $f$, i.e., the location of the jump $x_i$, the order of the derivative jumping $k_i$, and the amount of the jump $D_i$.

Is it unintuitive to ask such a question? Is such a thing not intuitively possible? I have been sincerely working hard for the past two years trying find an answer to this question, and I would sincerely appreciate suggestions and insights on this question.

**EDIT** (In view of comment by fedja)

We assume we have complete information about all the Fourier series/transform coefficients both magnitude and phase of all the infinite coefficients. I have mentioned the relation to be somewhat like asymptotic with the only reason that no 'finite number of Fourier coefficients can give any information about the singularities. That's why I expect the relations which give information about singularities need to involve all the infinite coefficients, and in this sense I used the word asymptotic, but we essentially assume we can utilize the full information about all the Fourier coefficients.

If we assume we do not have information about a finite number of Fourier coefficients, it would still not make any difference to the problem as these finite missing coefficients do not carry any info about the singularities, as they would form addition of a trignometric polynomial which is smooth.

**EDIT 2**

I am not interested in recontrsucting the function. There could  be a lot of functions which could possess the same singularities as the given function but different from the given function. I want a property of  the Fourier  transform/coefficients which is obeyed by all such functions.

**EDIT 3**

To make my point more precise, may I add that the method should be amenable to an algorithm with infinite computations. Would it be a legitimate thing? I may be not be quite right here, but let me try to express my interest. I assume we were given all (except some finite) the Fourier coefficients, but not in any closed form expression. Say they were supplied to us as real numbers data. Now I'd like know how to do computations on them to determine the singularities.

**EDIT 4** (after the answers by Igor Khavkine and Paul Garret)

I am seeking for something as rigorous as this theorem. Let the function $f(\theta)$ be a BV and periodic with period $2\pi$. Let $s_n(\theta)$ be the $n^{th}$ Fourier  series partial sum then, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{s'_n}(\theta)}{n} = \frac{1}{\pi}(f(\theta^+)-f(\theta^-))$$. Not exactly same or similar to  this, but it should be as rigorous as this theorem.

Comment: Depends on how "complete" you want the information to be. Also, by saying "decay of the magnitude", do you mean that we know $|\hat f|$ exactly or merely up to a factor that tends to $1$ (bounded by two constants, whatever) at infinity? Do we know anything at all about the phase in addition to the magnitude? All such tiny things may change the answer dramatically, so you'd better be as precise as possible in your question. The question itself is reasonable if you manage to state it so that it gets precise and non-trivial simultaneously. 

Comment: @fedja : I have added an edit in view of your comment. I am not sure, there could still be some loop holes which could make the question invalid/trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but the rules of the game are still unclear. The trivial way to find the jumps of $f$ or anything else we want with full information is to take the inverse Fourier transform and find the values of $f$ at any points that matter (using some summability methods, if some regularization is needed). I doubt you are interested in just that.

Comment: @fedja : Yes I am not interested in recontrsucting the function. There could  be a lot of functions which could possess the same singularities as the given function but different from the given function. I want a property of  the Fourier  transform/coefficients which is obeyed by all such functions.

Comment: @fedja : I guess I got it right now.

Comment: @fedja : I have made an  edit and have removed the word asymptotic which may not be necessary, and just mentioned it as what is the property/relation of fourier transform with the  jump singularities.

Comment: Almost. As I said, you do not need to reconstruct the full function, just the values at some relevant points. You can express those as some particular integrals and look at the asymptotic behavior of such integrals. It'll be shared by all functions.

Comment: @fedja : I understood what you have said, to make my point more precise, may I add that the method should be amenable to an algorithm with infinite computations. Would it be a legitimate thing? I may be not be quite right here, but let me try to express my interest. I assume we were given all (except some finite) the Fourier coefficients, but not in any closed form expression. Say they were supplied to us as real numbers data. Now I'd like know how to do computations on them to determine the singularities.

Comment: @TerryTao : It would be great if you have some time to make a comment on this question. I am sorry for pinging you this way.

Comment: This question sounds like it should be covered by the literature on Fourier-based edge detection, see e.g. http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642530

Comment: @Terry : Let $f$ be say $5$ times continuously differentiable and the $6$th derivative jump at some point say $a$,$b$,$c$. The literature you have mentioned, deals with the singularities at $a$,$b$,$c$. But these are not the only jumps singularities I want to deal with, there are more, for example, say the $10$th derivative of $f$ may jump at a point $x$ and $12$th derivative may jump at $y$. The literature you have mentioned does not deal with these type of singularities. I want a theorem which deals all these jumps singularities. 

Comment: @Terry : I request you to see this class of functions I described here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/100692/2987 to get an idea of the jump singularities $f$ could possibly have.

Comment: @TerryTao : My statement for this problem, I am trying to prove this : http://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414

Answer (score 3):

Consider functions of the form $s_k(x) = \Theta(x) x^k$, where $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. Then any function of the kind you describe can be written as $f(x) = g(x) + \sum_{i,k} (A_{ik} s_k(x-y_i))$, where the constants $A_{i,k}$ and $y_i$ determine the magnitudes of some finite number of discontinuities in derivatives of order less than $r$ and their locations, and $g(x)$ is $C^r$ regular. Obviously the same decomposition will be true for the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi)$. It is straightforward to compute the Fourier transforms $\hat{s}_k(\xi)$ and match them to the asymptotics of $\hat{f}(\xi)$ for large $\xi$. Essentially, they will decay as powers of $\xi$ and $\hat{s}_k(x)$ will always dominate $\hat{g}(\xi)$ for any $g(x)$ that is $C^r$ regular, with $r>k$.

Then, $\hat{f}(\xi) = \sum_k F_k(\xi) \xi^{-k-1}$, where each $F_k(\xi)$ is a finite linear combination of the form $\sum_i A_{ik} \exp(i\xi y_i)$. It should be straight forward to extract the locations $y_i$ and the jump magnitudes $A_{ik}$ if the $F_k(\xi)$ are known.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine : We do not even know how many $y_i$ are there nor the $A_{ik}$. ALL WE KNOW is $\hat{f}(\eta)$, thats all. I am looking for a strong mathematically rigorous result in the form of a theorem with full analysis. For example if to know the jump amount, may be we should be able to create a sequence and prove it converges to the jump amount at the point of jump, not necessarily same as this but a thorough mathematical result.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine : I think there is no mathematical rigour in your answer, and I'd like to know whether you agree with this.

Comment: @Rajesh, I was not trying to be rigorous in my answer. But I believe that the sketch of the argument that I gave can be turned into a rigorous one with some work, which I invite you to attempt. Of course, a rigorous theorem will depend strongly on the hypotheses you are willing to assume, and that is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine : Thank you very much for the answer and comment. I agree that my question isn't completely well defined. But my final goal is to get there. I sincerely appreciate the answer and would like to work more on this perhaps with some help. I also understand that it may be possible that while I try to get a precise statement, the entire thing may collapse into something trivial, but thats all right as atleast I would come to a conclusion positive or negative.

Comment: I mean "while I  try to get a precise statement of my question it could end up with a trivial answer." Fedja has already pointed this out.

Comment: My argument could help since it reduces your problem two the following ones: get the $F_k(\xi)$ from the $\hat{f}(\xi)$ and get solve the algebraic system $F_k(\xi) = \sum_i A_{ik} exp(i\xi y_i)$ for $A_{ik}$ and $y_i$. Both remaining problems are now algebraic equations, the first one is even linear. They are infinite dimensional, of course. However, your hypothesis that there are only finitely many discontinuities, should guarantee that there exists a finite number of $k$ and $\xi$ values to which the problem can be truncated and give the correct solution.


Comment: Rigor now comes down to how well you would be able to extract $F_k(\xi)$ from what you allow yourself to know about $\hat{f}(\xi)$.

Comment: @Igor Khvkine : I've made it clear that we assume we know $\hat(f)(\xi)$, for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ except on some interval of finite length. In terms of Fourier series we assume we know all the Fourier coefficients except a finite of them. 

But I still do not understand how we can recover $y_i$ using the method described by you.

Comment: we know $\hat{f}(\xi)$, but not in closed form expression though

Comment: You should concentrate on the $F_k(\xi)$ first.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine : I think we are no way near the solution. IMO we need a fresh outlook or idea from a totally different perspective.

Comment: My statement for this problem, I am trying to prove this : mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414

Answer (score 2):

Adding something to Igor Khavkine's good answer and examples: the question might be construed as talking about functions (additively) _modulo_Schwartz_functions_, for example. Thus, two functions with a jump discontinuity at the same finitely-many points, by the same amount, with the same left-and-right behaviors there, perhaps up to some fixed finite order, would fall into the same equivalence class. Fourier transform would respect the decomposition mod Schwartz functions. There are several reasonable choices for prototypes for functions otherwise rapidly decaying but with specified jumps. For example, the family of functions $x^\alpha\cdot e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ (and $0$ for $x<0$) allows specification of behavior at the jump $x=0$, and the Fourier transforms are readily computible: constant multiples of $1/(x+i)^{\alpha+1}$. Translation is obviously compatible. Thus, in this example, the asymptotics of a finite linear combination of the $x^\alpha\cdot e^{-x}$'s (and translates) at infinity (that is, modulo Schwartz) give (a finite amount of) precise information about the jumps.

Comment: My statement for this problem, I am trying to prove this : mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414

Answer (score 1):

The question of reconstructing piecewise-smooth (and periodic) functions from their Fourier series coefficients was considered in a series of papers by K.Eckhoff, who developed the so-called "Krylov-Gottlieb-Eckhoff method". See e.g.

- K.Eckhoff, "Accurate reconstructions of functions of finite regularity from truncated Fourier series expansions" (*Mathematics of Computation, 64 (1995): 671-690.*)

He showed that $\hat{f}(\xi)$ possess full asymptotic expansion, from which it is in principle possible to reconstruct the positions and the magnitudes of the jumps (and subsequently the point-wise values of the functions between the jumps). Recently, in the two papers

- D.Batenkov, Y.Yomdin, "Algebraic Fourier reconstruction of piecewise-smooth functions", (*Mathematics of Computation, 81 (2012), 277-318*), http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1884
- D.Batenkov, "Complete Algebraic Reconstruction of Piecewise-Smooth Functions from Fourier Data" (*to appear in Mathematics of Computation*), http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0680

we have modified this method and actually proved that the new method's rate of convergence is the maximal possible one. In particular, we provide an  explicit nonlinear algorithm to compute the singularities.

An important note is that **some kind of a-priori information** is necessary in all this business. For instance, you should assume that your jumps are not too small and not too close, otherwise finite number of integral measurements might not distinguish between them. In our papers we provide explicit quantifications of this kind.