# Is this statement which relates the Fourier transform of a function to its singularities correct?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, curves

I am working on a problem, which would possibly relate the Fourier transform/series with the jump singularities of the function where the function itself or one of its derivatives jump. ((some kind of logarthmic blow ups too, possibly as a corollary).

Consider a BV function $f(t)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(t) =0, t<0$. Let $F(\omega)$ be its Fourier transform.

Consider the family of curves $\alpha_t(\omega) \equiv (x_t(\omega),y_t(\omega)) $ given as
$$x_t(\omega) = \int_0^{\omega}R(\Omega)\cos(\Omega t + \Phi(\Omega))d\Omega$$  and $$y_t(\omega) = \int_0^{\omega}R(\Omega)\sin(\Omega t + \Phi(\Omega))d\Omega,$$ defined only for $\omega 
\ge 0$, where $R(\omega) = |F(\omega)|$ and $\Phi(\omega) = \angle F(\omega)$.

Let $A_t(s) \equiv (X_t(s),Y_t(s))$ be the arc length parametrization of the above mentioned curves. It can be seen that the transformation is $s(\omega) = \int_0^{\omega}R(\omega)d\omega$. We define the moment of inertia about center of mass of a segment of this curve corresponding to $t$, between $s_0$ and $s_1$ in arc length parametrization as $$I_{s_0,s_1}(t) = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} ((X_t(s)-X_{cm})^2 + (Y_t(s)-Y_{cm})^2)  ds, $$ where $X_{cm} = \frac{1}{s_1-s_0}\int_{s_0}^{s_1}X_t(s)ds$ and $Y_{cm} = \frac{1}{s_1-s_0}\int_{s_0}^{s_1}Y_t(s)ds$.

The moment of inertia about center of mass of curve segment ((corresonding to $t$)) between $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ is denoted as $$MI_{\omega_0,\omega_1}(t) =  I_{s(\omega_0),s(\omega_1)}(t).$$

Assumption : Assume $f(t)$ only has jump singularities in the form of  the function itself or one of its derivatives jumping at that point. For example $t_0$ is considered as a singularity if any derivative, say the tenth derivative $f^{(10)}(t)$ jumps at $t_0$.

**Statement :** Given that there is a jump singularity at $t = t_0 > 0$ then we can always find an $\omega_{oc}$ such that, for all $\omega_0 > \omega_{oc}$, given any arbitrarily samll $\epsilon$, we can find a sufficiently large $\omega_{0,\epsilon}$ such that for all $\omega > \omega_{0,\epsilon}$ the function in $t$, $MI_{\omega_0,\omega}(t)$ has a maxima in $(t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)$.

**PS :** Clarification : If the function $f$ is continuous at $t_0$ but say the tenth derivative
jumps at $t_0$, then also $t_0$ is defined as a jump singularity of $f$ in this problem. The function may have multiple jump singularities like third derivative jumping at $t_1$ and second derivative jumping at $t_2$, etc.

**Clues I had :**

I am trying to use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616106/2987) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/618993/2987), which I think is the key, but my limited ability to solve complex math or lack any sharp ideas, I am not able to attempt to solve it anymore. So I give up and post it here in this forum, where I hope to find fresh ideas and solution.

Things look interesting once we start looking from the geometric perspective of the plane where our curves are. Also to note, $f\cos(\theta) + f_h \sin(\theta)$, ($f_h$ being Hilbert transform of $f$) for different $\theta$ all have same singularities ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66095/2987)) at same places, only difference being partial blowup and partial jump, depending on $\theta$. (blowup being always logarithmic). This is in sync with  <s>follows from</s>  the translation and rotation invariance property of our moment of inertia about center of mass.

**Some non technical details :**

...I have been trying to formulate and prove this relation for the past 3.5 years. Most of my activity on math.SE and here was indirectly related to solving this. In fact I bumped into math.SE and mathoverflow when I started on this. [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/112060/14414) in particular was an attempt to know any existing theorems...). (..If proven this can be extended to functions in $\mathbb{R}^N$ using clifford algebra.

I guess this problem is very important for applied math. As far I know, definitely for signal processing.

**PS2 :** This concept exhibits duality, for example consider the real part of the Fourier transform as the function to begin with, then we can construct exactly similar things about the singularities of this real part function in frequency domain.

**Motivation :** For math greats like Terry and the likes and also for newbies like me, here is a motivation as to why this problem is so important.

Let $f(t)$ be an audio signal. We can safely asume it to be bandlimited to 0-20kHz as we cannot hear anything above that. Capture this signal in digital computer with appropriate sampling frequency and denote it as $f[n]$.

Now take Discrete Hilbert transform of $f[n]$ to get $f_h[n]$,  (using the code $f_h$ = imag(hilbert(f)); in Matlab).

Compute the signal $f_{\theta}[n] = f[n]\cos\theta + f_h[n]\sin\theta$ for any value of $\theta$, then listen to the signal with different values for $\theta$.

They all sound **exactly identical**.

Similarly our $MI_{\omega_0,\omega_1}(t)$ is same for all $f_{\theta} = f\cos\theta + f_h\sin\theta$, for any value of $\theta$.

just try it. $<f,f_h> = 0$, they why do they produce same effect in the listner?

**MATLAB code :**

[f,fs] = wavread('audio_file.wav');

fh = imag(hilbert(f));

theta = pi/4;

f_tht = f*cos(theta) + fh*sin(theta);

wavplay(f,fs);

wavplay(f_tht,fs);

**Some Illustrations for the problem :**

Some illustrations : (These are discrete approximations)

The function $f(t)$ (discrete version) is as follows :

[image]

The corresponding Moment of inertia $MI(t)$ (segment from zero to highest frequency) is as follows : (interesting to observe there is **no ringing!**)

[image]

Here is a plot of curves from $t = 0$ to $t = 800$. We can see that at $t = 400$, the curve is almost straight, making MI highest. $x-$axis is $f(t)$ and $y-$axis is $f_h(t)$.

[image]

Comment: Can someone kindly start a bounty on this question, Thanks

Comment: +1 so you have enough cash for a bounty!

Comment: @Carlo Thanks. 75 required for bounty previlege.

Comment: If not a complete answer, appreciate atleast please express your opinion on this question in form of comments/answers.

Comment: I would look back at the reference Terry Tao gave you in your previous question. The curve you're looking at $\alpha_t(\omega)$ is a partial inverse Fourier transform. Fourier inversion says that $f(t)=x_t(\infty)+i y_t(\infty)$. In general, $x_t(\omega)+iy_t(\omega)=(\chi_{(-\infty,\omega)}\cdot \hat f)^\vee$, so the operator $f\mapsto x_t(\omega)+iy_t(\omega)$ is a multiplier operator analogous to partial summation. Thus you might expect something like the Gibbs phenomenon to occur at discontinuities (which is mentioned in that reference Terry gave you).

Comment: Mark Lewko has a relevant discussion on his blog: http://lewko.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/lp-convergence-of-fourier-transforms/. The partial "summation" operator you're looking at is discussed in the first section, then he shows how to express it in terms of the Hilbert transform.

Comment: I was expecting people to question my motivation and reason to come up with such a statement and question its importance!

Comment: I wonder why this question couldnt garner enough attention. IMO the question is direct and simple and self contained. Isn't this question challenging enough to catch the attention of expert problem solvers?

Comment: [Meta MathOverflow discussion](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1717/how-can-i-convince-mathematicians-that-my-question-on-fourier-transforms-and-sin).

Comment: This concept exhibits duality, for example consider the real part of the Fourier transform as the function to begin with, then we can construct similar things about singularities of the function in frequency domain.

Comment: I found the formulation of $x_t$ and $y_t$ a bit confusing. Similarly to Brendan Murphy suggestion, I think a more appropriate formulation would be to use complex coordinates and investigate the function $\omega \mapsto \int_0^\omega \hat f(\Omega)\exp(t\Omega) d\Omega$ (the real and imaginary part of this are $X_t$ and $y_t$.

Comment: Don't you guys see the geometric view point in this problem?

Comment: Rajesh, you are being very aggressive in your tone and reactions to posts of others ("highschool stuff", "totally uncool useless stuff"), and it seems likely that you stifle any attempts to contribute here. You should not insult people that are trying to help you. Since you like colorful images: It's like, you are cutting of the branch of the tree that you are sitting on.

Comment: @Kofi : Appreciate it. removing those comments.

Comment: Also se this metric space : math.stackexchange.com/a/522662/2987

Comment: I've recently filed a patent using this metric with a slight change, instead of arccos i used sqrt(2(1-cos(theta))), which makes it a Hilbertian metric. I had then embedded this metric space into an Hilbert space isometrically, to model using vectors.

Comment: just try it. $<f,f_h> = 0$, they why do they produce same effect in the listner?

Comment: The signals $f$ and $f_h$ have the same magnitude in the Fourier domain and adjacent frequencies have the same relative phases, so they interfere in the same way.  This determines what we hear.  It is well known in the audio community that our perception of sound does not involve the global phase; phase only matters insofar as it affects interference between nearby frequencies.  Put another way, the observation you make in your motivation is what would be expected, but this is a point about perception and not math.  Are you independently interested in the mathematical question?

Comment: @NoahStein : "Profound study of nature is the most fertile source of mathematical discoveries" - J. Fourier. I am interested in math and physics and nature.

Comment: @NoahStein : means ofcourse I am independently interested in the question. I am the one who formulated it!

Comment: @NoahStein :  As a genius, I see an opportunity in it. $<f,f_h>=0$, then why do they sound same? Thats how I see opportunity to revive the way the entire mathematics being used in physics and signal processing.

Comment: Note that $\cos(at)$ and $\sin(at)$ also sound the same (and yet are orthogonal). This is because your ear encodes the sound wave by having different parts of the basilar membrane resonate with different frequencies; as such, you effectively hear the spectrogram, i.e., your ear is "blind" to global phase, as Noah Stein suggested. This is a crucial idea in speech processing, see for example "On signal reconstruction without phase" by Balan, Casazza and Edidin.

Comment: @NoahStein : "It is well known in the audio community that our perception of sound does not involve the global phase", that is english. What if I define mathematically a metric space of signals which says $d(f,f_h) = 0$. Constructing pure mathematics for perception of sound. See this metric space : math.stackexchange.com/a/522662/2987 I've recently filed a patent using this metric with a slight change, instead of arccos i used sqrt(2(1-cos(theta))), which makes it a Hilbertian metric. I had then embedded this metric space into an Hilbert space isometrically, to model using vectors.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/864838/2987

Comment: Can i publish this in any leading math Journals/conferences ?

Comment: Is anyone interested to collaborate with me on this problem? I have lot more to offer on its applications. If interested, you may mail me at rajeshlearnstorock@yahoo.com

Comment: Rajesh, if you are so insistent for one of us to work on your question, you could either stop insulting us, or start paying us, or both. Does it ever occur to you that professional mathematicians might be busy with their own interests and with the demands of the day job?

Comment: @BrendanMurphy : I think I found a generalization of this problem to $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$, but for that formulation, I first need to prove a (possibly a very cool) statement on pointwise convergence of multidimensional Fourier transform, which i am going to ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer as to why $MI_{\omega_0,\omega_1}(t)$ of $f_\theta$ is the same for all $\theta$, which is one of the motivating questions.

First, let $f_\theta=f\cos\theta+f_h\sin\theta$, where $f_h=\mathcal{H}f$ is the Hilbert transform of $f$. Then let
$$
z^\theta_t(\omega)=(\chi_{(0,\omega)}\,\hat f_\theta)^\vee,
$$
where $\chi_{(0,\omega)}$ is the indicator function on the interval $(0,\omega)$,
so that for $\theta=0$, $z^\theta_t(\omega)=x_t(\omega)+iy_t(\omega)$, with $x_t$ and $y_t$ as in your original notation.

Now let $\mathrm{sgn}$ be the function equal to $x/|x|$ if $x\not=0$ and $0$ if $x=0$. It is well known (see wikipedia) that
$$
\widehat{\mathcal{H}f}=-i\mathrm{sgn}\,\hat f.
$$
Thus
$$
z^\theta_t(\omega)=(\chi_{(0,\omega)}\,(\cos\theta\hat f -i\sin\theta\,\mathrm{sgn}\,\hat f))^\vee.
$$
Since $\mathrm{sgn}$ is always equal to 1 when restricted to $(0,\omega)$, it follows that 
$$
z^\theta_t(\omega)=(\chi_{(0,\omega)}\,(\cos\theta\hat f -i\sin\theta\,\hat f))^\vee=e^{-i\theta}(\chi_{(0,\omega)}\,\hat f)^\vee.
$$
Thus $z^\theta_t(\omega)$ is just a rotated version of $z^0_t(\omega)$ and hence has the same moment of inertia.

Comment: Hey @Brendan thanks. Thats great indeed. What do you think about the idea i gave in my answer to the main question?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, it's a neat problem, but unfortunately I don't have the time to work on it more. At this point it seems like a matter of persistence, so you may answer the question on your own if you keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to prove for the case of jump discontinuity of the function itself. (rather than that of one of its derivatives).

Let $t_0>0$ be a point where $f$ jumps. The curve $$(X_{t_0}(s),Y_{t_0}(s))$$ is asymptotic to the straight line $$(\frac{(f(t_0^+)+f(t_0^-)}{2},s)$$ which is parallel to the y-axis. For any other $t\ne t_0$, the curve $$(X_{t}(s),Y_{t}(s))$$ approaches to a point $(f(t),f_h(t))$ in the plane, as $s\to \infty$ .

Let us fix $s_1$ and let $M_{t_0}(s) = I_{{s_1},s}(t_0)$ and $M_t(s) = I_{{s_1},s}(t)$. Since the curve corresponding to $t_0$ is asymptotic to a straight line, we can say that $$M_{t_0}(s) \sim O(s^3)$$ and the curve corresponding to $t$ being smooth and converging to a fixed point in the plane, making the entire curve lie in a bounded region of the plane, we can say that $$M_t(s) \sim O(s)$$.

Hence as $M_{t_0}(s)$ dominates $M_t(s)$ for large $s$, the result follows for the jump discontinuities of the function $f$.

Comment: By any other point $t \ne t_0$, I mean any point $t$ where the functions $f$ does not have a discontinuity.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/864838/2987

Comment: Is anyone interested to collaborate with me on this problem? I have lot more to offer on its applications. If interested, you may mail me at rajeshlearnstorock@yahoo.com