# A question about pointwise convergence of Fourier transform in $N$-dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

**I am retreating back on this statement, after some explorations and calculation**
Bow to Willie and others who were skeptical on this. Main difficulty can be seen in this [reference](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/efaa32db37c4234e4e8a2b2d9cd3b330/mzm7569.pdf). But I must mention that my quest for jump discontinuities has not seen a dead end but a new light after this failure. I am very much interested in this class of functions and this kind of jumps, and have found a new way to deal with them in 2 dimensions. My new pursuit: A direction dependent jump can be converted to jump of a 1-d function via Radon transform, reflecting jumps in different directions at some point into separate 1-d jumps via Radon transform. Via Fourier slice theorem, such 1-d jumps can be dealt with different slices of FT of the image using a [1-d technique](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414) ).  Cant wait to lay my hands on image signal processing.

The initial question was in $N$ dimensions which follows after the heading "Initial question". But in view of Willie's comments, I realized it has flaws, but I am still optimistic, and hope they are not fatal.

So I'd like to formulate and pose the question for the simple case of $N=2$, with which I am at comfort, considering my limitations with higher math, and then hope it can be generalized to $N>2$ by mathematicians. I seek their help in this regard.

**Case of $N=2$**

Main motivation is monochromatic image signal or any 2-d signal. Mathematically We represent it as a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. I know image signal has compact support, but for mathematical convenience, we can always place zeros where ever it is not defined and extend its domain to $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Atleast I do this blindly just for mathematical beauty).

**Definition-1** A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be of bounded variation, if for every rectifiable curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the 1-d function obtained by
restricting the domain of $f$ to the curve, is a function of bounded variation in 1-d sense.

(Motivation for this definition : For the following definition to make sense, and for the limits defined in it to exist always.)

**Definition-2** : Directional limits. Given a point $\hat{x}_0 = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, for every $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ we define a directional limit as $$u_{\theta}(\hat{x}_0) = \lim_{r\to 0+} f(x+r\cos(\theta),y+r\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta))$$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Definition-3** : Limit function. We define a limit function $J_{\hat{x}_0} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for every point $\hat{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ given as $$J_{\hat{x}_0}(\theta) = u_{\theta}(\hat{x}_0)$$

**Definition-4** Class of functions $\mathcal{V}$ consists of all functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the following two conditions.

1. $f$ should be a function of bounded variation as per **Definition-1**.
2. For every $\hat{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the associated limit function $J_{\hat{x}_0}(\theta)$ (as in def-3) should be a function of bounded variation when its domain is restricted to $[0,2\pi)$.

**Problem**

Let $f \in \mathcal{V}$ be a square integrable function and let its Fourier transform be $\hat{f}$. Given any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we define a directional partial sum $S^{\theta}_r : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as $$S^{\theta}_r(\hat{x}) = \int\limits_{-rcos(\pi/2-\theta)}^{r\cos(\pi/2-\theta)}  \int\limits_{-rcos\theta}^{r\cos\theta} \hat{f}(k_x,k_y) e^{i(xk_x+yk_y)} \mathrm{d}{k_x} \mathrm{d}{k_y}     $$ where $\hat{x} = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Is the following statement true?**

Given any $\hat{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and any $\theta \in [0,\pi)$ $$\lim_{r\to\infty} S^{\theta}_r(\hat{x}_0) = \frac{1}{2}(u_{\theta}(\hat{x}_0) + u_{(\pi-\theta})(\hat{x}_0) )$$

---

#### Higher dimensional case revisited

**Definition 1** Let $\Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth submanifold. A function $f:\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to have *bounded variation* if for every rectifiable curve $\gamma\subset \Sigma$, the composition $f\circ\gamma$ has bounded variation in the usual one-dimensional sense.

Now, let $\Sigma \subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth submanifold and let $x\in \Sigma$. We write $\exp_x: T_x\Sigma \to \Sigma$ to denote the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Riemannian_geometry).

**Definition 2** Let $\Sigma$ be a $d+1$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $f:\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}$. Fix $x\in \Sigma$ and $\omega\in T_x\Sigma$ a unit vector. We write the *directional limit*
$$ f_\omega(x) := \lim_{t \to 0+} f\circ \exp_x(t\omega) $$
whenever the limit on the right hand side exists. If for every unit vector $\omega\in \mathbb{S}^d \subset T_x\Sigma$ the directional limit $f_\omega(x)$ exists, we write $J_x: \omega \mapsto f_\omega(x)$. Note that $J_x:\mathbb{S}^d \to \mathbb{R}$.

**Definition 3** Let $\Omega$ be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$. We say that a function $f$ belongs to the class $\mathcal{V}(\Omega)$ iff $f$ has bounded variation and that at every point $x\in \Omega$ its blow-up $J_x$ has bounded variation, both in the sense of Definition 1.

**Definition 4** Given $\omega\in \mathbb{S}^{N-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, we write $\omega_i$ to be the $i$th coordinate value of $\omega$ relative to the standard rectangular coordinate system. We can define the rectangle $R_r^\omega$ for $r > 0$ to be
$$ R_r^\omega = (-r |\omega_1|, r|\omega_1|) \times (-r |\omega_2|,r|\omega_2|) \times \cdots \times (-r|\omega_N|, r|\omega_N|)~,$$
in other words the rectangle with sides parallel to the standard hyperplanes and with diagonal $r\omega$. We also define $\mathrm{sgn}(\omega) = \prod_{i = 1}^N \mathrm{sgn}(\omega_i)$.

Now let $f\in \mathcal{V}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Denote by $\hat{f}$ its Fourier transform. Fix $\omega\in \mathbb{S}^{N-1}$. Write
$$ S_r^\omega f(x) = \int_{R_r^\omega} \hat{f}(\xi) \exp(i x\cdot \xi) \mathrm{d}\xi~. $$

**Question**

Is it true that

$$ \lim_{r \to\infty} S^\omega_r f(x) = \frac12 [J_x(\omega) + J_x(-\omega)] $$

for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\omega\in \mathbb{S}^{N-1}$?

---

#### Initial question

This is a question about pointwise convergence of a Fourier transform of functions of the form $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, which is potentially a $N$-dimensional generalization to pointwise convergence of $1$ dimensional Fourier transform. This question arose when I am trying to generalize [this statement](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414) to $N$-dimensions.

**Definition 1** : Functions of bounded variation in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
Given any rectifiable curve in $\mathbb{R}^N$, if the function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ evaluated on this curve is a function of bounded variation in the 1-d sense, then we say $f$ is a function of bounded variation.

Definition : Directional Limits.

for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, given a unit vector $\bf{\hat{a}}$, we define the directional limit of $f$ at a point $\bf{x_0} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ along $\bf{\hat{a}}$ as $u_{\bf{\hat{a}}}(\bf{x_0}) = \lim_{\alpha \to 0^+}f(\bf{x_0 + \alpha \hat{a}})$.

Limit function at a point $x_0$ denoted as $J_{\bf{x_0}}:S^{N-1} \to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as $$J_{\bf{x_0}}(\bf{\hat{a}}) = u_{\bf{\hat{a}}}(\bf{x_0})$$. We denote this jump function in $\theta$-coordinates as $J^{\theta}_{\bf{x_0}}:[0,2\pi)^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R}$

**Definition of a class of functions** (This definition is recursive)

Given $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, we define a set of functions $\mathcal{V}(\Omega)$ with the following properties.

Iff $f \in \mathcal{V}(\Omega)$ then

1. $f:\Omega \to\mathbb{R}$ is square integrable and function and of bounded variation as per **Definition 1**.
2. With an additional constraint that the limit function in $\theta$-coordinates, at any point $P \in \Omega$ , denoted as $J^\theta_P: [0,2\pi)^{N-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ also belongs to the class of functions $\mathcal{V}([0,2\pi)^{N-1})$.

**Fourier partial sum**

Consider a function $f \in \mathcal{V}(\mathbb{R}^N))$, and let its Fourier transform be $\hat{f}$. Given any unit vector $\bf{\hat{a}} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, and a positive real number $R$, we define Fourier partial sum as  $$S^{\bf{\hat{a}}}_R : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$$ defined as $$S^{\bf{\hat{a}}}_R(\bf{x}) = \int_{-R\cos(\theta_1)}^{R\cos(\theta_1)} \int_{-R\cos(\theta_2)}^{R\cos(\theta_2)} ...\int_{-R\cos(\theta_{N-1})}^{R\cos(\theta_{N-1})} \int_{-R\cos(\phi)}^{R\cos(\phi)} \hat{f}(k_1,k_2,k_3,...k_N) e^{i(k_1x_1+k_2x_2+...+k_Nx_N)} \mathrm{d}{k_1}\mathrm{d}{k_2}...\mathrm{d}{k_N}$$ where $[\theta_1,\theta_2,...\theta_{N-1}]$ is $\bf{\hat{a}}$ expressed in $\theta$-coordinates, and $\phi = \frac{\Phi_{N-1}}{2^N} - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{N-1} \theta_j$ where $\Phi_{N-1}$ is the total solid angle subtended by the full surface of a unit $(N-1)$-sphere given as $$\Phi_{N-1} = \frac{2\pi^{\frac{N-1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{N-1}{2})}$$

$\bf{k} = [k_1,k_2,...k_N] \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\bf{x} = [x_1,x_2,...x_n] \in \mathbb{R}^N$

**Statement**

Question is that whether the following statement is true?

Given any point $\bf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, and any unit vector $\bf{\hat{a}} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $$\lim_{R\to \infty} S^{\bf{\hat{a}}}_R(\bf{x}) = \frac{u_{\bf{\hat{a}}}(\bf{x}) + u_{\bf{-\hat{a}}}(\bf{x})}{2}$$

Comment: @TerryTao and other Harmonic analysis experts, what do you think about this problem. Also let me know the defects in it, especially the formula for $\phi$, I am not sure I got it what I intended it to. Thanks

Comment: A few random comments: (1) the domain of definition of $J_P^\theta$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$. (2) What is $\theta$-coordinate? You are identifying $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ with essentially $\mathbb{T}^{N-1}$ and that is problematic in my opinion. (3) What's up with $\phi$? By your definition when $N = 3$ you have $\phi = \frac{4\pi}{8} - \sum_{j = 1}^2 \theta_j$ so when $\theta_1 + \theta_2 > \pi/2$, which happens for a large chunk of $[0,2\pi)^2$ your $\phi$ is negative. // Did you come up with all these definitions yourself? If so please include motivations on why such defn.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that my point (1) above is meant to say that it makes no sense to define $\mathcal{V}(\Omega)$ recursively because $[0,2\pi)^{N-1}$ is not open.

Comment: Hi @WillieWong : Thanks for the valid points. I just realize they hamper but hope they are not fatal. So I have edited the question to give a version for $N=2$, with which I am at comfort and clear with my intentions and leave it to mathematicians for $N>2$, if at all its possible in a meaningful way. I hope my motivations for definitions are clear with the $N=2$ case.

Comment: @Willie : I made up these definitions on my own and they dont have any sanctity except to explain the question in a easy manner. My main motivation is generalizing http://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414 to images and $N>2$ ( but only for jumps of function rather than any of its derivatives). I have moved away from jumps of derivatives of the function altogether.

Comment: @Willie : I can replace $[0,2\pi)^{N-1}$ with the open set $(0,2\pi)^{N-1}$ without any loss as the function is $2\pi$ periodic, so i hope that would rectify the recursive definition. But i still agree there are flaws.

Comment: Od there any good source/book which has all the machinery to prove/disprove such a result for N=2. I still think result hold except at theta = npi/2.

Comment: A too-short answer, but it seems that any comment would likely get lost in the others... Also, not responding directly to the literal question, but to the context: the notion of "wave-front set" would seem to me to be one of the concepts the questioner might find useful in refining the formulation of the issue (e.g., refining to the point that the assertions are not easily shown faulty in various ways, e.g., coordinate-(in)dependence as @WillieWong comments).

Comment: @WillieWong : There are a couple of places you have typos/missing dollar in equations in "Higher dimension revisited". Request if you could correct them. 1. exp^x, 2. a limit not under $$."

Comment: H. Hardy 1 . On double Fourier series, and especially those which represent the double zeta function with real and incommensurable parameters. I don't have access to it. Wonder what was Hardy doing with double zeta function and its Fourier series?

Comment: My first goal now is to establish localization principle for rectangular partial sums, for this class of functions. I need some solid references and papers. I dont have access to any math journals, so any help will be appreciated. Especially the Cesari-Tonelli result I've heard established localization principle for a wider class of functions. I don't have access to it.

Comment: Please explain the downvotes!

Comment: Related : http://mathoverflow.net/q/187215/14414

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **No**.

Consider the 2D case. Let $\theta = n \pi / 2$ for $n \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. From your definition $S_r^\theta f = 0$, since on the RHS of its definition you are integrating over a null set. But clearly the corresponding $u_\theta(x) + u_{-\theta}(x)$ doesn't always vanish: consider in particular any non-trivial Schwartz function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It still does not kill the spirit of the problem. In this problem, for N=2,  for each element (unit vector) in $S^1$ we are giving out (contemplating) a statement to hold. If I recall correctly, to cover $S^1$ we need atleast $4$ co-ordinate charts.

Comment: (CONTINUED..)...So we need to make the statement $4$ times each for each co-ordinate chart, and when we change co-ordinate chart, we lso need to take care to rotate all the co-ordinate systems associated with the problem appropriately (including domains of $f$ and $\hat{f}$ and then make the statement. When we do that, I hope each of the directions $n\pi/2, n=0,1,2,3$ will be covered in one of the co-ordinate charts without the problem of integral becoming zero as you have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: (CONTINUED..)... I don't have the ease to make such statements in mathematical language and I hope you appreciate the spirit and if meaningful, write those statements in a new version of the problem. It would be great if all comes out beautifully.

Comment: **If** your result is coordinate dependent, then it'd be useless, especially since the right hand side of the putative equation does not depend on coordinate choice. And no, you don't need 4 charts to cover $\mathbb{S}^1$. You are free to investigate further, but I don't think your line of reasoning is likely to go anywhere. Essentially it seems to me that you want to be able to say that when the inverse Fourier integral is not absolutely convergent, that you can somehow pick out directional dependence by taking the limit in different ways. That idea in itself is not impossible....

Comment: ... but I don't see any reason why the particular method you take to enforce this directional dependence is the preferred one. It is especially suspicious since the method itself is not invariant under rotations of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Agree that they are not co-ordinate dependent. There was some confusion. I mean to say that the result holds for all $\theta$ except $n\pi/2$. The $n\pi/2$ are singular, in the sense that they screw up the summation region to null inspite of indefinite growth of $r$. So how do we deal with the jumps in the direction of say $y$-axis? just rotate the entire image by an angle say $\pi/4$, then our old $y$-axis is not in direction any $n\pi/2$ so the result holds there in the new rotated image.

Comment: Concerning the $n\pi/2$, it seems to me that they are the effects due to choice of using rectangular co-ordinates in the entire problem. If at all we had used circular/spherical co-ordinates and circular harmonics for Fourier transform, things could have been a bit different meaning problematic things would be different from $n\pi/2$. What do you think about this fancy analysis of the problem?

Comment: If you are in for a complete co-ordinate independence, then people might question the choice of  fourier transform, why not Fourier transform in spherical co-ordinates? but they don't seem to give same results.

Comment: My first goal now is to establish localization principle for rectangular partial sums, for this class of functions. I need some solid references and papers. I dont have access to any math journals, so any help will be appreciated. Especially the Cesari-Tonelli result I've heard established localization principle for a wider class of functions. I don't have access to it.

Comment: @RajeshD: the Fourier transform **is** coordinate independent in the sense that the Euclidean group of symmetries augmented by the dilations and scaling act predictably on the Fourier transform. In particular, rotating your function in physical space can be balanced out by a rotation of your function in frequency space. Your characterisation, however, is not symmetric with respect to that.

Comment: I do not understand the problem you are mentioning. Lets just say N=2, The only problem right now is that the statement is not true for $n\pi/2$. But this problem is not permenant. If one were to retrieve physically the values on $n\pi/2$ lines, we just need to rotate the image physically by any angle not equal to $n\pi/2$, the FT too gets rotated and our old $n\pi/2$ lines are not $n\pi/2$ any more, so we can retrive values on original $n\pi/2$ lines, using the directional sums. Please let me know what exactly is the problem you were mentioning causing suspicion of result.

Comment: Rotate your function by angle $\theta$, compute the directional sum relative to the rotated version of $\vec{v}$. Compare that to the directional sum relative to $\vec{v}$ of the original function. Why would the two limits even be the same? You are exhausting the plane now using two different families of sets and you assert that the limit should both converge to the same thing. In the case the Fourier transform is absolutely integrable, sure, you have the required limit. But in that case your question is trivial. The $n\pi/2$ case is just the extremum where this inequality is explicit.

Comment: My speculation is that two limits of directional sums are equal, except when $\angle{\hat{v}} = n\pi/2$. Hope we are on the same page now.

Comment: Lets suppose that at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $J_x(\omega) = f(x) \forall \omega \in \mathbb{R}$, meaning there is no jump in any direction, then all directional partial sums (except those in the directions of $n\pi/2$) converge to $f(x)$, due to the a theorem that any rectangular partial sum $S_{m,n}f(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ when $m,n$ independently tend to $\infty$. (I dont have reference on net as I don't have access to any online journals)...

Comment: (Contd.).. This adds heavy value (not proof by any means) to my arguments and also justifies the isolation of directions $n\pi/2$, as the directional sum in these directions cannot be termed as rectangular partial sums.

Comment: +1, I am backing off on this statement, but found new directions.

Comment: Any ideas how you would proceed to make the limit direction dependent? Any ideas/suggestions?